# Can router give the same public IP to 2 different networks?

Tags: networking, router, virtual-machine, ip, nat

I have set up a virtual machine and specified an IP address for it **that is outside my home network**. I cannot ping this machine and access it through the Internet from my host machine. I presume it is due to the fact that my **ISP gives out only one public IP** for my entire network and thus my VM is left without one.

**Is there any scenario where the same public IP can be used for different networks?**

I guess if we make sure distinct ports are used it could *theoretically* work out, but is there any place where this occurs already in practice?

Comment: No. You need to get an extra IP from your ISP. Here, often in groups of 6 IP addresses

Comment: Reverse proxy can direct incoming traffic to the appropriate host based on hostname or other options.

Comment: You misunderstand the subject : The public IP belongs to your router, not to a computer or a VM. The VM can't have a different IP.

Comment: @harrymc so there is a different reason that I cannot access my VM from the Internet? Because then all the VM needs is to be able to connect to the router. And two devices in different networks can be connected to the same router using two different router interfaces: one for each network

Comment: Please study better the subject before asking.

Comment: You would need to hook up the VM to a separate network. This can be done with USB pass through. But you need a second external IP.

Comment: @harrymc then tell me, please, where exactly I am wrong, so I will know what to study better

Comment: Look up NAT (Network Address Translation) and how it fits your needs. It will describe how you can have your LAN accessible behind one single WAN address.

Comment: @Silbee I understand what NAT is. I don't understand why can't private IP from a different network be translated

Comment: The best you can do with a single IP is port forwarding.  Where you program your router to forward port(s) to different internal IP addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do wonder if the question you asked represents what you are trying to establish.  I suspect the answer is somewhat academic to you.

**Is there any scenario where the same public IP can be used for different networks?** -

Yes.

When an ISP does Carrier Grade NAT multiple networks are hidden behond a pool of IP addresses.  A number of different networks may share the same IP (at the same time).

Its not ideal but possible for the same IP address to appear in multiple locations in some CDN setups.  I imagine this has been largely superceded.

It is possible for an IP to be allocated and then then disconnected and reallocated.  This means the IP is used on multiple networks but only one at a tome - and still within the ISPs control.

Intercepting firewalls (like the great firewall of China) may advertise and route IP addresses differently to intercept traffic.

Its probably a configuration error unless used in a CDN config, but if dynamic routing goes wrong this can happen - but it will split the Internet.

The last one is a cop-out now, but the Internet used to be AN internet - It is technically posdible to run your own IPv4 (or IPv6 network and connect up with a whole lot of others and ignore the existing Internet. 30 years ago that concept was not an anathms - but I expect ut is now.

Comment: Anyone know why the downvote?

Comment: Probably because you were supposed to support the gang and downvote my question instead of answering it. That brutally violates the community guidelines

Comment: Anyway, as for your answer, does it require an additional setup/configuration for the same public IP to be shared between the two different private networks? That's the only reason I see why my VM in another network cannot access the Internet

Comment: My answer is accademic.  All my cases require the assistance or involvement of an ISP and have serious side effects and costs.  As an end user you cant assign an arbitrary IP address on the Internet - it needs to be given to you by your Internet provider as part of the block they control.

Comment: no, I mean, if I'm able to connect another network to the gateway, I could still use the same one IP adress given to me by ISP before

Comment: Most likely not.  Almost all ISP's do egress filtering which will prevent traffic from your router leaving their network.  Even if it did get to its destination it would return to tje olf ISP's network...

Comment: Even if you were still connected to the old ISP as well, chancrs are your router would likely not correctly reverse the NAT as they would appear on the old interface...

Comment: The exception is if you arrange a BGP session with both providers - but normally that requires a direct relationship between the providers or you to own the IPs (minimum a class C) and have an AS [autonomous system] number and appropriately powerful router - effectively you become a multihomed network provider.